# How does $2\sin^2x\cos^2x$ simplify to $\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was encountering an integral question just now. I was stuck in the step of

> $$2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

And I looked though the solution, it is simplified to $$\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}$$

Can I know how to simplify it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are showing the simplified form, so what more do you need ?

Comment: To integrate it, you should further convert it to $$\frac{1-\cos 4x}{4}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $2\sin { x } \cos { x } =\sin { 2x } $ so $$2\sin ^{ 2 } x\cos ^{ 2 } x=\frac { 4\sin ^{ 2 } x\cos ^{ 2 } x }{ 2 } =\frac { { \left( 2\sin { x } \cos { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =\frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }{ 2 } \\ $$

Answer (score 1):

$$2\sin^2x\cos^2x=\frac12\sin^2(2x)=\frac{1-\cos(4x)}4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Start from

$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x
\implies \sin^2 2x=4\sin^2x\cos^2x$

Divide by 2 both sides, and you get
$\frac{\sin^22x}{2}=2\sin^2x\cos^2x$